# How to write this query in jooq

Tags: java, sql-server, jooq

```
select sum(x.amt) from (select amount as amt from user_transactions where TransactionTimeStamp > '2022-03-09') as x
```

I am not able to convert this sql query to jooq query. Please help

Comment: Having never written it, a brief reading of [the docs](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual-single-page/) seems to indicate something like: `YourContext.select( sum(user_transactions.amt) ).where( user_transactions.TransactionTimeStamp.greaterThan( Date.valueOf("2022-03-09") ) ).fetch()` What have you tried so far?

Comment: SO isn't a code translation service. You need to research it, try solving it yourself, then, IF you run into a problem, ask a question about a specific problem. See "[ask]" and "[mre]" and their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

#### Creating derived tables

You can create [derived tables](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/derived-tables/) like this:

```java
// Assuming this static import, as always:
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;

Table<?> x = table(
    select(USER_TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT)
    .from(USER_TRANSACTIONS)
    .where(USER_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP.gt(
        LocalDate.parse("2022-03-09")
    ))
).as("x");
```

And then use it like this:

```java
ctx.select(sum(x.field(USER_TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT)))
   .from(x)
   .fetch();
```

#### Alternative using `FILTER`

jOOQ supports the standard SQL [`FILTER`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/aggregate-filter/) clause, and can emulate it also for SQL Server:

```java
ctx.select(sum(USER_TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT).filterWhere(
       USER_TRANSACTIONS.TRANSACTIONTIMESTAMP.gt(LocalDate.parse("2022-03-09"))
   ))
   .from(USER_TRANSACTIONS)
   .fetch();
```

This is especially useful if you're [aggregating several things in a single query](https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-calculate-multiple-aggregate-functions-in-a-single-query/), e.g. with different filters